# What is the syntax of creating an if statement for multiple ID's in a .tpl file?

Tags: if-statement, prestashop, smarty

I got this little piece of code: `{if $smarty.get.id_cms == 1 }`

I would like iterate on every cms page with the id 1 to 20. Rather than creating 19 more if statements.

I tried to use "," and ";" without any success.

Using "," or ";" breaks the page into whiteness. Indicating that my 'guessed' syntax is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I must've been under the influence.

Of course it was as easy as

```
{if in_array($smarty.get.id_cms, array (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20))}
```

Comment: glad you found a way, for this specific example, where you're checking for all values between 1 and 20, you could also use `range(1,20)` saving you some time to type all this up :)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
{if $smarty.get.id_cms => 1 &&  $smarty.get.id_cms <= 1}
```

Regards